# Registering new voice commands from my app to iOS Voice Control engine

Tags: ios, iphone, uiaccessibility, mobile-development, voice-control

Does anybody know if Apple iOS API allows to add new commands to build in iOS Voice Control engine. I noticed that Voice Control can control phone application using names, nicknames from address book. It can also play music list from default iOS music player app. I would like in my app to register new voice commands for this Voice Control engine and handle some actions based on recognized commands. I was searching in developer documentations but can't find anything like that. Am I missing something?

Comment: as far as i know, it is not possible!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's an iOS 13 new feature called **Voice Control** that may help you reach your goal:
[image]

> I would like in my app to register new voice commands for this Voice Control engine and handle some actions based on recognized commands.

This is definitely possible thanks to the `Customize Commands` - `Create New Command...` menu:
[image]

If you need dedicated names to be read out for some items in your app, use the **`accessibilityUserInputLabels`** property to define them.

Following this rationale, you can now **register new voice commands from your app to iOS Voice Control engine**.

Answer (score 0):

IOS till now not exposed any API's related to voice. However it is achievable using CMU Sphinx.

Big advantage of CMU Sphinx - it works offline.

Comment: I'm looking for solution that only works offline and understand Polish words like in iOS when siri is turned off after holding home button. When siri is off and language is set to Polish iPhone understands pretty well in offline. I'm designing an application for use in car during driving and I need that this is working offline. I'll check Sphinx. Thanks.